# jQuery variables containing numbers return as NaN when trying to add

Tags: jquery

I am trying to grab 2 numbers that are contained in spans (these numbers are determined by choices from a select menu), and add them together. This number I then need to populate into another span showing a total. The numbers inside the spans are valid numbers, but every time I click .getTotal the results are returned as NaN. Any thoughts?

```
 $(".bundelTotalHeading").hide();
 var pestTotal = $('.programCostPestControl').val();
 var lawnTotal = $('.programCostLawnCare').val();
 var total = parseFloat(pestTotal) + parseFloat(lawnTotal);
 $('.getTotal').click(function () {
       if(isNaN(total)) {
              var total = 'CALL FOR PRICING';
       }  
       $(".totalCost").text(total);
       $(".bundelTotalHeading").show();
 });
```

Comment: try .text() instead of .val()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move  your variable declarations inside the click handler, and to get the text inside spans you want to use .text() not .val():

```
$(".bundelTotalHeading").hide();

 $('.getTotal').click(function () {
     var pestTotal = $('.programCostPestControl').text();
     var lawnTotal = $('.programCostLawnCare').text();
     var total = parseFloat(pestTotal) + parseFloat(lawnTotal);
       if(isNaN(total)) {
              var total = 'CALL FOR PRICING';
       }  
       $(".totalCost").text(total);
       $(".bundelTotalHeading").show();
 });
```

Comment: Ahhhh of course!! I was going code blind!! Thanks so much!!

Comment: Just as an FYI, you can swap out `isNaN` for `total != total`. It's a little known trick that works since `NaN` is not equal to any other value including itself. [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L2bvbntb/) According to [jsperf.com](http://jsperf.com/isnan-vs-quick-nan-check) it's substantially faster as well. Either way +1...